# Cancel an non-cancellable kotlin flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow, cancellation

I have a non cancellable flow from external library and I need to make it cancellable. The idea is to either wait for flow completion or timeout after 1 second. I'm trying to recreate second situation with timeout:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val infiniteFlow = infiniteFlow()
    val finiteFlow = finiteFlow()
    merge(infiniteFlow, finiteFlow).flowOn(Dispatchers.IO).collect {}
}

private fun infiniteFlow() = flow<Unit> {
    while (true) {
    }
}

private fun finiteFlow(): Flow<Unit> {
    return flow {
        delay(1000)
        throw RuntimeException("end")
    }
}
```

So what I'm expecting is that finite flow will throw an exception after 1 second. Since `merge` operator takes both flows, it should notice exception thrown from finite flow and close itself. But to my surprise this merged flow never ends - why?

Comment: This won't work because merged flows are allowed to fail independently from each other. As far as I can tell from looking at the `merge()` source code, it swallows all exceptions until all the merged flows complete, then it rethrows the first one it received. Can we get any hints about what the third-party flow looks like? If it doesn't co-operate with cancellation, there may not be any solution to this. Maybe you can cancel collecting it, but if it's blocking some thread, there's no way to stop it from doing that and leaking itself forever, even if it isn't being collected anymore.

Comment: Thanks Tenfour04, it helps a lot. Third party library asks external device via bluetooth to get some data - it opens a stream and proxies data from external device via flow. The problem is that device might never respond (due to connectivity issues), so I need to be prepared for case in which flow might never emit any value at all.
So my idea was to merge their flow with my flow, which was periodically checked if timeout occurs.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is the question. Do you ask how to cancel non-cancellable code? Non-cancellable is... well, not cancellable, so this is not possible. If you ask how to timeout the flow (your example is more about this) then it depends if you mean the whole flow has to finish in a given time or it should timeout if we don't observe any new items for a given time.

Comment: But is this flow (improperly) blocking in between emissions? How did they even achieve being not cancellable with the `cancellable()` operator without blocking between emissions?

Comment: @mtw I commented at the same time as you did, so I didn't read your comment before writing. So is your case that you need to cancel only if the first item exceeds the timeout and after that subsequent items are not restricted with a timeout? What about "non-cancellable" that you mentioned in the question?

Comment: I think I need to raise a bug in library since indeed there is nothing I can do here. This must be cancellable flow, but it seems I cannot convert it by myself. In my case I'm waiting for a second for expected data and if by that time I don't get expected data, I need to stop collecting this flow. So if this flow is not cancellable then it is a memory leak, because cancel() on this flow would be ignored. So I guess you solved my problem, thanks guys.

Comment: Is it an OSS library you can link to? Just curious how they implemented this Flow. The obvious way to implement it is with the `callbackFlow` builder, which would force it to be cancellable.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Why not something like: `flow { while (true) { emit(read()) } }`? That would make it not cancellable. Although, I would expect blocking IO to throw an exception in the case of IO problems and not simply freeze. Freezing indeed seems like a solution based on callbacks.

Comment: @broot, I understand it could be written that way, but it’s such absurdly bad code I’d be surprised that it made its way into a library that is being used. I’m curious if there’s a more *seemingly* innocuous way it could be implemented.